# Is it bad practice to have both build server and subversion server as same machine?

Tags: svn, cruisecontrol.net

Is it bad practise to have both build server and subversion server on the same machine?
Previously they have been separate machines, but I wondered if it is really a waste of resources having them separate.

In addition can these be deployed to a virtual server, will the performance be degraded much if they are VMs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it depends mostly on how much load each server is facing. If they're lightly loaded, I can't think of much reason they shouldn't be the same machine. For large software projects though, build servers tend to work really hard, so in that case keeping the two separate makes more sense.

Comment: Agreed. Anywhere even near 'normal' usage, version control is not resource intensive. Typical VC system processes some requests when somebody checkouts or commits, but that's usually it. With Git, many of the operations don't even contact the master server. Having CI and VC in the same server is more of a benefit to me than anything else.

Answer (score 1):

With regards to virtuals, our SVN server and both of our CruiseControl.Net servers are virtuals.  All three are sufficiently fast for our needs.  Of course that has as much to do with resource allocation (CPU, memory, drive space) as anything else.